# Parameter must be assigned upon exit

Tags: c#

I am trying to use `ConcurrentDictionary`'s TryRemove with lambda out how ever i get the error message `Parameter must be assigned upon exit`

Code:

```
_reminders.TryRemove(identifier, (out Reminder reminder) =>
{
    //Here i am trying to remove the item from the dictionary and instantly use the out
    //of it to perform action on it.
    reminder.Cancel();
});
```

Why ?

because i find this code a little bit ugly

Code:

```
Reminder rm;
_reminders.TryRemove(identifier, out rm);
rm.Cancel();
```

Comment: Neither one of your code alternatives works.  The first one has at least two compilation problems and the second one will fail if `rm` is null.

Comment: @recursive no it doesn't fail here.

Comment: @DanielEugen Try passing in a identifier that is not in the dictionary, you will get a null reference exception on `rm.Cencel()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I can think of is an extension method like this:

```
static void TryRemoveAndPerformAction<TKey, TValue>(
    this ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, 
    TKey key, Action<TValue> action) 
{
    TValue value;
    if (dict.TryRemove(key, out value)) action(value);
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
_reminders.TryRemoveAndPerformAction(identifier, rm => rm.Cancel());
```

Comment: Your edit would appear to work, but I voted to reject since it changed the meaning.  Of course, you should still use that code if you prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

[Per the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f1hz171.aspx), method parameters declared with the [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx)  or [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) parameter modifiers are passed *by reference* rather than by value. This allows the called method to change the value in the caller's scope.

The difference is that parameters declared with `ref` **MAY** be assigned a value prior to returning from the method, but parameters declared with `out` **MUST** be assigned a value prior to returning from the method.